# Configuring different JDK log formatting for different log files

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

Using `java.util.logging`, is it possible to set up different formatting for different log files?  For one file, I want to use the default `SimpleFormatter` output.  The other file contains logging from a specific class, and I want to output just the `LogRecord` message without any formatting.

Ideally, I'd like to do this purely from configuration.

Comment: why not use something like log4j which does support this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create some java code to get this to work.  Create a new `Formatter` to return the `LogRecord` log message without formatting.  Then use the `config` option described in the top level class documentation of the [LogManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html) to attach your `FileHandler` with the `SimpleFormatter` and your `FileHandler` without formatting.